# Jax-Rs 2.0.1 throwing NotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I am trying to deploy my web application on TomEE plus and at the time of deployment, jax-rs throws a long error. Using 2.0.1 version of jaxrs-api dependency in maven. I saw a few solutions suggesting usage of version greater than 2.7 for jaxrs-api. But I am restricted to usage of versions not more than 2.0.1. Here's the error:

```
WARNING: No root resource matching request path /documents-core/ has been found, Relative Path: /. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
Jan 20, 2016 1:29:40 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse

WARNING: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toNotFoundException(SpecExceptions.java:87)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toNotFoundException(ExceptionUtils.java:117)
.... 20 more
```

Comment: Are you using the version of TomEE that includes a JAX-RS runtime?  jaxrs-api is *just* the API and needs a JAX-RS runtime to go along with it.  Alternately, you can include something like Jersey as a Maven runtime dependency.

Comment: I haven't provided any runtime like jersey or resteasy. That makes sense. Thanks :)